# adding an img src that is not on the same computer as the html files

Tags: html, image, video

I am updating a website that we only have access to an admin panel, so the source html and css is on a companies servers and we only update the content using an admin panel. In certain sections we can add HTML.

I want to create a page of photos and I have the following html

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Example</title>
  <style>
   .cards {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   align-items: flex-start;
   flex-direction: row;
   max-height: 100vh;
  }
.cards img {
   margin: 10px;
   border: 3px solid #000;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
   max-width: 23vw;
 }
 </style>
<main class="cards">
**<img src="hole 8.jpg" alt="Sample photo">**

</main>
```

I know the line specifying the src for the image will only work as it currently is if the img is in the same folder as the html file. Unfortunately, this isn't the case and the image is on my computer.

Is there a way to display the image or video without uploading it to another website? I have a western digital mycloud drive which is connected to my router and always on. I can access photos on this from outside of my network but I have to log in so I suppose it wouldn't work in this instance.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need a local server (e.g. XAMPP, IIS etc) to host images on a network path

Comment: Thanks you, I have realised I can upload photos that I have saved on googledrive. But A video I had worked initially but now it no longer works. The video element appears but no video plays.